# Importing Photoshop Brushes for Grease Pencil and Texture Mapping?

Tags: texture-painting, grease-pencil

Not sure if anyone has asked this before, but is it possible to import Photoshop brushes into Blender 2.8 for both Grease Pencil and Texture Mapping? Here are some brush samples of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Not directly, but is there and example of the kind of brush or texture result that you want to emulate? I can try to dig around and find some alternatives if you can give examples to imitate.

Comment: @CraigDJones Thanks for answering. I provided an image above. I was thinking of something complex like brushes that are heavy with textures.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking at Grease Pencil and it is not using procedural textures as masking or in the brush yet - though you can set up an image texture to repeat along the stroke or as a fill inside the stroke. I know a lot about Texture Paint and using image painting to get these effects, but it isn't something I know how to apply to Grease Pencil. I would be wasting your time if I took you down the route of texture painting to get the same effect. If you want to know how to manipulate the texture paint brushes, I can help there.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just looking for a way to import existing Photoshop brushes without manipulating the existing texture paint brush/brushes in Blender, if that's at all possible. Appreciate the response.

Comment: Only way I have been able to use them is by capturing a single image result of the brush and then manipulating settings in blender to imitate the behavior. There isn't a native way to import Photoshop brushes into Blender that I know of, been using Blender as a painter for many years now. possibly this coudl be a good feature request over at rightclickselect.com

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and ask over at rightclickselect.com. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Perhaps these tutorials can help: [How to Use Photoshop Brushes in Other Programs](https://www.lifewire.com/use-photoshop-brushes-in-other-software-1701560) (specifically exporting them as PNG files) [Grease Pencil Textured Brushes - Blender 2.80 Beta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpY-WVQUxYw) [Creating your own custom Grease Pencil brushes (Blender 2.8)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abZxp-fHUSA) (using PNG files with mask)

Answer (score 8):

There is a way around this. You can convert photoshop custom brushes (ABR files) into PNG files using the free OpenSource programme [ABRViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/abrviewer/). Alternatively just save a masked PNG that you want to use as a brush.

Using Grease Pencil in Blender 2.8 make sure you're in **Draw** mode. Then click on the Active tool tab. Change brush name and make other changes to settings you might want.

[image: fig 1]

Then add a new material (in material tab). Under the checked **Stroke** section change **Style** to Texture.

[image: fig 2]

Under this will appear an **Open** box. Click this to browse for the brush PNG you want to use.

[image: fig 3]

I change Mode Type to Dots.
If you want to use your own colour, rather than the colour of the brush, check **Use As Stencil Mask** and then change **Color**.

[image: fig 4]

Perhaps these tutorials can help:

[How to Use Photoshop Brushes in Other Programs](https://www.lifewire.com/use-photoshop-brushes-in-other-software-1701560) (specifically exporting them as PNG files)

[Grease Pencil Textured Brushes - Blender 2.80 Beta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpY-WVQUxYw)

[Creating your own custom Grease Pencil brushes (Blender 2.8)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abZxp-fHUSA) (using PNG files with mask)